# Creating a data matrix

Tags: python, bash, awk

I am a data scientist and am working with a text file that specifies how many datasets I have for a specific participant by printing the participant's ID on a new line for each dataset. The second column counts the number of different participants, like so

> a 1
>   a  1
>   a  1
>   b  2
>   b  2
>   c  3
>   d  4
>   d  4
>   d  4

I now need to create a matrix which has a column for each participant and specifies what lines refer to that participant by giving it a value of 1 vs 0. I have over 2000 participants, so I cannot do this by hand or write out all column numbers and what to print where but have to create a rule.

The number of columns in my file will be the number in the last row of column 2 + 2 (in the example that should be 4 + 2 = 6). Basically, for each row, I need to print a 1 in columns that match the (value in column 2 (participants number) + 2). For that row, all other columns get the value of 0. So for row 1, column (1+2=)3 gets a 1, all other columns get a value of 0. For row 2, column (1+2=)3 gets a 1, all other columns get a value of 0, etc.

This should look like this:

> a 1  1  0  0  0
>   a  1  1  0  0  0
>   a  1  1  0  0  0
>   b  2  0  1  0  0
>   b  2  0  1  0  0
>   c  3  0  0  1  0
>   d  4  0  0  0  1
>   d  4  0  0  0  1
>   d  4  0  0  0  1

I wish I could provide code that I have tried, but I don't know where to start.

Hope anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if(max<$2)max=$2; next} 
              {printf "%s %s", $1,$2; 
               for(i=1;i<=max;i++) printf " %s", i==$2; 
               print ""}' file{,}

a 1 1 0 0 0
a 1 1 0 0 0
a 1 1 0 0 0
b 2 0 1 0 0
b 2 0 1 0 0
c 3 0 0 1 0
d 4 0 0 0 1
d 4 0 0 0 1
d 4 0 0 0 1
```

with this double scan algorithm the consistency and order doesn't matter.